# Docker Compose containers not showing up when starting them with a bash script via cron

Tags: bash, docker-compose, cron

I am using a bash script to start Docker Compose containers every hour with a cron job. When I run docker-compose up -d manually, I can see the running containers with docker-compose ps, and I can shut down the containers with docker-compose down. However, when I run the same commands using a bash script via a cron job, the containers are not showing up in docker-compose ps, and docker-compose down does not stop them. I can still see the containers running with docker ps.

Here's my bash script that starts the Docker Compose containers:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Rebooting docker compose..."
COMPOSE_FILE_PATH="/root/production/pharma_data/docker-compose.yml"
compose_directory=$(dirname "$COMPOSE_FILE_PATH")
cd "$compose_directory"
docker-compose -f "$COMPOSE_FILE_PATH down >> /tmp/docker_compose.log 2>&1
sleep 90
docker-compose -f "$COMPOSE_FILE_PATH" up -d >> /tmp/docker_compose.log 2>&1
echo "Done!"
```

I have set up a cron job to run this script every hour:

```
0 * * * * cd path/to/scripts && script.sh >> /path/to/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

The cron.log file shows the following output:

```
Rebooting docker compose...
Done!
```

After the script runs, docker-compose down does not stop the containers, and docker-compose ps does not show any running containers. However, I can see the containers running with docker ps.

What could be the cause of this issue, and how can I modify my script so that I can still use docker-compose commands to manage the containers after starting them with the script?